# Equivalence relations on a set with restrictions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is the way to calculate how many equivalence relations are there on $\{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}}$ that contain the set $\{{(6,4), (4,7), (3, 3), (5,1)\}}$ but don't contain the set $\{{(1,2), (6,1), (2,4)\}}$ ? 
I really don't  understand how to approach this kind of question... Can someone give me a hint on where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Concentrate on *partitions* of the set. Such that $6$ and $4$ are in same component (et cetera) and $1$ and $2$ are in different components (et cetera).

This number of partitions equalizes the number of equivalence relations that satisfy.

---

Explanation.

There is a one-to-one correspondence between equivalence relations on a set and partitions of that set.

Every equivalence relation on a set induces a characteristic partition on that set. Its components are the equivalence classes. Conversely every partition on a set induces a characteristic equivalence relation on the set. If $x,y$ are elements of the set then pair $\langle x,y\rangle$ will be element of that relation iff $x,y$ belong to the same component.

Comment: Hmm... I see that 4 and 6 must be in the same component but this is impossible... Is this a contradiction?

Comment: Impossible? How about $\{4,6,7\},\{5,1\},\{2,3\}$ then?

Comment: So I get $\{{4, 6, 7 ... \}}$ and $\{{1,5 ... \}}$ and $\{{2 ... \}}$ and only the number 3 left to add. So I think the answer is 4 equivalence relations?

Comment: I think you are correct. Nice approach, right?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! (:

Comment: You are very welcome.